# MongoDB convert ObjectId to string in result on fly

Tags: php, mongodb

If document has fields with value as `MongoId` object, it will be returned to php something like http://dl.dropbox.com/u/7017985/Screenshots/26.jpg, is there any way how to return it like simple strings and not as `MongoId` object.

Why I need it ? Because I need to send result to javascript browser side. I have document which has 2-3 fields which is refs to another document, and they keep as `ObjectId`.

Answer (score 0):

MongoID supports `__toString`. If you cast it as a string, or call `__toString` directly, it will convert the value to a string.

Comment: I know that, but it means I have to go through whole result :( and this is what I would like to avoid

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe there is.

MongoDB takes input and output in the form of BSON documents whose `ObjectId` field takes this particular formation.

This is something you cannot change.

Answer (score 0):

You could loop through the query results and convert all MongoId objects to strings. The below function will convert all ids if given either a single result array from MongoCollection::findOne(), or a MongoCursor result from MongoCollection::find().

```
function convert_mongoid_to_string(& $mongo_object)
{
    foreach($mongo_object as $mongo_key=>$mongo_element)
    {
        if(is_array($mongo_element)||is_object($mongo_element))
        {
            if(get_class($mongo_element) === "MongoId")
            {
                 //cast the object to the original object passed by reference
                 $mongo_object[$mongo_key]=(string)$mongo_element;
            }
            else
            {
                //recursively dig deeper into object looking for MongoId's
                convert_mongoid_to_string($mongo_element);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //is scalar so just continue
            continue;
        }
    }
    return $mongo_object;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your solution, it is totally clear for me, But I had search for db side solution, seems it is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

I've needed the MongoIds to be javascript/json (client side) friendly so I wanted to convert multiple mongoIds transparently. I couldn't find any build-in functionality to achieve this, but came up with the following solution:

```
<?php
function strToMongoIdObj(Array $_ids) {
    return array_map(function($id) {
            return new MongoId($id);
        }, $_ids);
}

function mongoIdToStr(MongoCursor $cursor) {
    $rs = array();
    foreach ($cursor as $doc) {
        $doc['_id'] = (string)$doc['_id'];
        $rs[] = $doc;
    }
    return $rs;
}

$_ids = array("522dbdd29076fde9057bb5ed",
              "522dbf229076fdeb053f5b7b");

$m = new MongoClient();
$cursor = $m->db->col
    ->find(array('_id' => array('$in' => strToMongoIdObj($_ids))));

print_r(mongoIdToStr($cursor));
```